# PHP: How to return just one RSS item?

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have this code for displaying an RSS feed:

```php
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('rss.xml');
 echo 'RSS feed title: '.$xml->channel->title.'<br/>';
 echo 'RSS feed link: '.$xml->channel->link.'<br/>';
 foreach($xml->channel->item as $value)
 {
  echo 'Item title: '.$value->title.'<br />';
  echo 'Item description: '.$value->description.'<br />';
  echo 'Item link: '.$value->link.'<br />';
  echo 'Item pubDate: '.$value->pubDate.'<br />';
 }
```

This displays the entire RSS feed, but how can I adjust it so that only one item from the RSS feed is shown, rather than the whole feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't loop and access first element of the array

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('rss.xml');

echo 'RSS feed title: '.$xml->channel->title.'<br/>';

echo 'RSS feed link: '.$xml->channel->link.'<br/>';

echo 'Item title: '.$xml->channel->item[0]->title.'<br />';

echo 'Item description: '.$xml->channel->item[0]->description.'<br />';

echo 'Item link: '.$xml->channel->item[0]->link.'<br />';

echo 'Item pubDate: '.$xml->channel->item[0]->pubDate.'<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a beginner with PHP hence the question being a bit simple.